# ServiceBusTrigger not found in basic Azure Function project

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have created a brand new .NET Core 3.1 Azure Function project using the Visual Studio template

I am using V3 of the functions, i.e. the version created by the template

I have the latest VS - 16.10.2

Straight away, it fails with ServiceBusTrigger and Connection not found?

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

```
namespace AzureFunctionTest
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("AzureFunctionTest", "Research Subscription", Connection = "eventbus-connection")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```

Really strange how a template from MS itself does not work and a bit concerning this fails on the first hurdle!!

Here are the relevant parts of my project file

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus seems to be the latest package and the one recommended to use

What am I missing?

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` package. [Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/4.3.0).

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) official documentation for further information.

[image]